# Qt QSqlRelationalTableModel can we specify column name instead of column index?

Tags: qt, qtsql

For example, when we're calling `QSqlRelationalTableModel::relation(int column)`, we must specify a column index. If we change the DB model later (e.g. adding a column), things will be broken down. Is it possible to obtain column index by specifying a column name, by which we can do `model->setRelation('xxxId', xxx)` instead of `model->setRelation(2, xxx)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yeah, I missed that there are `model->fieldIndex('column_name')`, so you can do `model->setRelation(model->fieldIndex('column_name'), xxx)`.